# Build my own autocomplete angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

Im trying to build my own search function with auto complete.

```
Search MAC:<br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="boxtext">

<tr ng-repeat="box in boxes | filter:boxtext">
  <td>{{box.type}}</td>
  <td>{{box.mac}}</td>
  <td>{{box.serial}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The problem I have now Is that all rows from boxes are printed out, and the filtered when I start typing In the text field.

I really don't know how to print out the rows from "boxes" when I start typing In the text field? Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you take a look on this: [np-autocomplete](http://ng-pros.github.io/np-autocomplete/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add an [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to the preview table:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="boxtext">

<table ng-if="boxtetxt.length > 0">
 <tr ng-repeat="box in boxes | filter:boxtext">
  <td>{{box.type}}</td>
  <td>{{box.mac}}</td>
  <td>{{box.serial}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This way the table is removed as long as `boxtext.length > 0` is false. Note that `boxtext` has to be initialized to an empty string, or it will be `null` or `undefined` and will not have a `length`.

Comment: OFC! I did that, but on my tr-tag, which did not work.. Thank you :)

Comment: @Bryan Happy that it helped. If that answers your question, accept the answer so the question shows as answered